# desktop freezes

Tags: arch-linux, video

My System: 
    Arch 4.8.8-2 
    Gnome 3.22.2 
    Graphics card: Radeon HD7770
    Graphics driver: radeon (xf86-video-ati-1:7.5.0-1)

Since I did an update, my screen freezes after some time, most of the time when starting a video or opening an additional tab in Firefox... Since the beginning of this problem, I suspect a video problem...

I already read some stuff, and one solution was to change the Pointer Theme. I was a bit hesitating, but indeed it solved it a bit, it took much longer before the screen froze again. However, when doing some "intense" stuff, it still freezes.

I looked at the systemd journal, and found nothing specific at the time the screen freezes...

I can get out of the freeze by doing `killall -HUP gnome-shell` through a remote SSH session. Switching to another terminal (CTRL-ALT-F2) does not do anything...

Does anybody know what I have to do to solve this?

Comment: When suspecting video problems under x11, d'better look into xorg logs (generally in /var/log) than into dmesg.

Comment: Not to say that I don't know what you updated précisely... (If 4.8.8 is your kernel... certainly not your kernel...) 4.8.8 being quite old and... I think deprecated... you could well have updated something to some version incompatible with your kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer.
I had faced a similar situation in Ubuntu and Debian. 
In my case turned out that upgraded kernel (4.6 in my case) was for some reason not working correctly with my Intel graphics card causing the screen to freeze randomly. 
Quite strange since previous kernel (4.4) and next kernel (4.7) had not this problem.

If your last update was including a kernel upgrade you could boot with an older kernel to see how it goes.